# Hibernate Update giving java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying the below code . Basically I am trying to update a row in database table through Hibernate.

```
ABCEntity obj = new ABCEntity ();       
obj.setMetal(MetalEnum.valueOf(metal));
obj.setName(smelter_name);
obj.setSmelterId(smelter_id);
obj.setReferenceName(smelter_name);
obj.setId((long) 117806);

try {
         // Saving in Known Smelter Table
        Transaction tx = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();


         sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(obj);

         tx.commit();
  } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("Print object "+ obj.toString());
        logger.info("Error for update: "+ e.getMessage());
  }
```

So tracing the error log I am getting :

```
Print object   ABCEntity@447a43f7[
  id=117806
  name=XYZ  SMELTER
  smelterId=ABC001
  metal=METAL_A
  referenceName=XYZ  SMELTER
  nextSteps=<null>
  mineNames=<null>
  mineLocation=<null>
  comments=<null>
]
```

and

```
Error for update: null
```

What is the mistake here .

Comment: If your database does not allow null values then there would be error. Make sure nextSteps, mineNames, mineLocation and comments are nullable.

Comment: Please post ABCEntity.java, as well provide more stacktrace of error, and execute again one more time after making showsql true in your hibernate_cfg.xml and post the output of log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this sequence for updating a row in database using hibernate

1st get the row you want to update, you can have a findByID() method

using criteria

```
public ABCEntity findById(Integer id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            ABCEntity instance = (ABCEntity) getSession()
                    .createCriteria(ABCEntity.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq(IDABCENTITY, id)).uniqueResult();
            return instance;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            throw re;
        }
    }
```

using hql

```
public ABCEntity findById(Integer id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         try {
                ABCEntity instance = (ABCEntity) getSession().get(
                        "packageofclass.ABCEntity", id);
                return instance;
            } catch (RuntimeException re) {
                log.error("get failed", re);
                throw re;
            }
        }
```

then reference the object

```
ABCEntity obj = findById(1);
```

2nd is to update what field should be change, for example i want to change the name

```
obj.setName("new name");
```

then to update the row you can do this

```
public void update(ABCEntity transientInstance) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            getSession().saveOrUpdate(transientInstance);
            return transientInstance;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            re.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: make sure you map your column correctly in your entity.

Comment: One question this @ using criteria will not work for new insert right ?? As then `instance` will be `null` .  So `saveOrUpdate` which should work for both will not work?

Comment: for new insert you can use sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(instance); before calling the update you should first check if the instance that you retrieved is not empty ofcourse. and for update only you can use the method update(instance) too in getSession().

Comment: `ABCSmelterEntity instance = (ABCSmelterEntity) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    .createCriteria(ABCSmelterEntity.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("smelterId", smelter_id)).uniqueResult();
                          if (instance != null){
    instance.setName(smelter_name);
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(instance);
   }else{
    logger.error("get failed", obj.toString());
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(obj);
   } `

Comment: save(obj)? you mean save(instance);

Comment: Ok so I was trying for new insert `save(obj)` it should be `save(instance)` right?

Comment: exaclty. but you would want to set the values some of your fields in ABCSmelterEntity

Comment: Yes I will set it in `instance` object then I will save it fine?

Comment: if the ABCSmelterEntity does not exist in your database or your uniqueResult() fails you make a instance=new ABCSmelterEntity(); to make a new object in your else clause then set the fields and it will save fine.

Comment: Ok I got you . So i was trying in else `ABCSmelterEntity obj = new ABCSmelterEntity();  obj.setMetal(MetalEnum.valueOf(metal));
  obj.setName(smelter_name);
  obj.setSmelterId(smelter_id);
  obj.setReferenceName(smelter_name); sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(obj);`  Will it work ?

Comment: if you have a new object and not null it should work fine :) if you are using autogeneratedid, i mean autoincrement in your database coulumn. you could not set it. hibernate will generate the number for you